# ACF Curve Interpretation

Tags: time-series, interpretation, acf-pacf

[image]

How to interpret this acf curve?

Comment: Your timeseries has trend and seasonality, judging by a declining pattern starting at 1.

Comment: These are hourly measurements?

Answer (score 0):

Without some context, not much can be said about your timeseries on the basis of that acf plot alone. The higher autocorrelation value around lag 24 might indicate this is an hourly series.  If so, what we can read is that this is a highly autocorrelated series, with some daily structure. But the presented part of the acf function covers then about two days, so nothing can be said about longer timespans.

If this is *not* an hourly series, so the max around lag 24 is a coincidence, I would want more information about he series. But it *might just* indicate some strong trend. Or something else ...